# change a lib file to to another location centos 7

Tags: repository, centos7, space, arangodb

I'm using centos7 , and I'm a newbie 
I' have installed arangodb rpm creating the repo at /yum.repos.d/ in root .
and arangodb3 is installed in /var/lib/arangodb3 location 
this directory is used and I have another directory /home where there is space left . 
how can I switch it to the free directory .
running df - h I get :

```
[root@cloudera-manager log]# df -h
Sys. de fichiers        Taille Utilisé Dispo Uti% Monté sur
/dev/mapper/centos-root    50G     50G   20K 100% /
devtmpfs                  7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     7,8G     33M  7,8G   1% /run
tmpfs                     7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                 497M    218M  280M  44% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home   442G     14G  429G   3% /home
tmpfs                     1,6G       0  1,6G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                     1,6G       0  1,6G   0% /run/user/994
cm_processes              7,8G       0  7,8G   0% /run/cloudera-scm-agent/process
[root@cloudera-manager log]#
```

I want to move it to another location / home

Answer (score 0):

The `arangodb` rpm installs under /etc, /usr/bin, /usr/bin, /usr/share, /var/lib, /var/log, /var/run.  Based on your df output, all of these would map to your root partition.  So it would be difficult to relocate this package elsewhere.  (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323532/yum-install-package-name-to-different-directory)

A better idea might be to measure your disk usage and relocate your biggest users of disk space to /home.  For example, /var/log which has logfiles usually takes up a lot of space.

Two commands that will help are `du` and `find`.

The `du -s` will show the largest directories.

```
# du -s /*/* | sort -n
```

The `find` command will show files larger than 10MB.

```
# find / -size +10M
```